# Calculate a variable from a list in r

Tags: r

I have a list of letters with their corresponding value and I have a variable with letters. I would like to convert the letters of the variable to the values of the list.

```
vlt <- list(A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3, E = 4, F = 5)
lt <- c(E, A, D, D, F, A, A, C, E, E, C, B)
```

The result should be

```
lt 
[1] 3 0 3 3 5 0 0 2 4 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subscripting as shown.  Omit the `unlist` if you want a list as the result.  The names on the result as the original values.

```
vlt <- list(A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3, E = 4, F = 5)
lt <- c("E", "A", "D", "D", "F", "A", "A", "C", "E", "E", "C")

unlist(vlt[lt])
## E A D D F A A C E E C 
## 4 0 3 3 5 0 0 2 4 4 2
```

Comment: Yes, but the result could be in a new variable as numeric?

Comment: The result is numeric.  You can use <- to assign it to a variable.